# Append child element to all SVG nodes with the same class

Tags: javascript, svg

I have the following code which generates some random images on an SVG canvas.

What I want to do is use the code under the //this bit// comment to append an animate node to all the elements with a specific class.

However, the code below does not work... and for the life of me I cant figure out why, could anyone point me in the right direction

```
function createBackground(){
    var loopLimit = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);

    for(var i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        var jpgSelecter = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
        var thisItem = document.createElementNS( svgNS, "image" ); 
        thisItem.setAttributeNS(null,"id","node_" + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));
        thisItem.setAttributeNS(null,"class","node" + jpgSelecter);
        thisItem.setAttributeNS(null,"x",(Math.random()*500)+1);
        thisItem.setAttributeNS(null,"y",(Math.random()*500)+1);
        thisItem.setAttributeNS(null,"width",(Math.random()*500)+1);
        thisItem.setAttributeNS(null,"height",(Math.random()*500)+1);
        thisItem.setAttributeNS(xlinkns,"xlink:href","images/blobs" + jpgselecter + ".png");

        document.getElementById("SVGcanvas").appendChild(thisItem);
    }
```

//This Bit//

```
    var animate = document.createElementNS( svgNS, "animateTransform" );
    ani.setAttributeNS(null,"name","transform");
    ani.setAttributeNS(null,"begin","0");
    ani.setAttributeNS(null,"type","rotate");
    ani.setAttributeNS(null,"from", "0 180 50");
    ani.setAttributeNS(null,"to","360 180 50");
    ani.setAttributeNS(null,"dur","4");
    ani.setAttributeNS(null,"repeatCount","indefinite");

    var tenner = document.getElementsByClassName("node_10");
    for(i=0; i<tenner.length; i++)
    {
        alert(tenner[i]);
        tenner[i].appendChild(ani);
    }

}
```

**Update**

I've edited my code, this doesn't throw up any errors however the animation node doesn't get appended.

Comment: A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing a 'working' example that reproduces the problem would be helpful, in addition to the OS/browser/version that you are experiencing this problem on. (It may be that you're doing everything correctly but the browser has a bug.)

Comment: Tip: `setAttributeNS(null,…)` is equivalent to `setAttribute(…)`.

Comment: Hi James, the alert fires... but nothing gets appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. You create an `animate` element, but then attempt to set attributes on an `ani` object and append this object to all classed elements.
2. Even if you change `animate` to `ani`, you cannot append the same element to multiple children. Your loop will place the element on the first found class, and then move it to the second found class, and so on. Instead, you need to create a copy of it for each item. So, either do this:

   ```js
   for(var i=0; i<tenner.length; i++){
     var ani = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'animateTransform');
     // set all attributes
     tenner[i].appendChild(ani);
   }
   ```

   …or do this:

   ```js
   var ani = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'animateTransform');
   // set all attributes
   for(i=0; i<tenner.length; i++){
     tenner[i].appendChild(ani.cloneNode(true));
   }
   ```